# Int does not contain a constructor that takes one argument

Tags: asp.net, constructor

In my .NET application, I recently had to make some changes in the database structure and upon changing code I have run into this error message. 
The line used to say `_categoryID = new Guid(Request.QueryString["CategoryID"].ToString());` which worked fine to retrieve a list of products based on the categoryid, but now I had to add a top level category called Market, and I used `int` instead of `Guid` in the database, because to me using `Guid` is a pain. 
But now when I change the line I mentioned to `_marketID = new Int32(Request.QueryString["MarketID"].ToString());` I get the error. 
Here is the chunk of code :

```
#region  Variables
    Int32 _marketID;
#endregion
if ( Request.QueryString [ "MarketID" ] != null )
{
   _marketID = new Int32(Request.QueryString["MarketID"].ToString());
   ViewState["MarketID"] = _marketID;
   BindDataToUI ( );
   CreateFilterInSession ( );
}
```

Comment: `Request.QueryString` returns a `string`. There's no need to call `ToString()` on it. (Not the actual error, just trying to point something else out)

Comment: `_marketID = (int)Request.QueryString["MarketID"];`

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever :) The whole switching from using Guid to int has kind of been a hassle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
_marketID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["MarketID"]);
```

note : no need to use `ToString()` for querystring values, they're all natively strings anyway.